# Noun to describe someone who always knows the right things to say

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word response for someone who always knows the right things to say in any situation. For example:

> Taylor got us out of trouble with the police. What a ___.

Comment: Smooth operator?

Comment: What a persuader. (If you're looking for a more classical take. Someone who presents a persuasive argument.) Not a cliché either. :)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three somewhat positive nouns:

- Smooth Talker (or Smooth Operator)
- Schmoozer
- Charmer

If it is to be negative one could use:

- Snake
- Deceiver
- Liar
- Wolf
- Cajoler
- Coaxer

Possible adjectives could be:

- Resourceful
- Astute
- Quick-witted
- Charismatic
- Charming
- Intuitive
- Crafty

Answer (score 1):

**diplomat** (noun):

Defn. 1.1 - A person who can deal with others in a sensitive and tactful way.

> *"You need to be an organiser, negotiator, diplomat and entertainer, ready to deal with anything and everything."*

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diplomat)

Answer (score 0):

Wordsmith:

> Taylor got us out of trouble with the police. What a **wordsmith**.

Comment: wordsmith suggests working on or writing a text. Not speech directed at a cop.

Comment: A definition would be helpful here.  Perhaps the [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=wordsmith) dictionary or the [Oxford](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wordsmith) dictionary.

Comment: @Lambie The cop example was just an example - I was answering the question more generally. Oxford seems to infer *any* skilled usage of words, so perhaps there's an American/British difference in meaning here?

Comment: *Taylor has a **way with words*** would seem to capture the meaning the questioner is seeking, but it's not a single-word-noun.

Comment: Sigh, there is no difference of that kind. I guess you mean Oxford seems to imply.....not infer. :) No worries. For me, to stop the cops you have to be a persuasive speaker. What the dictionary does not tell you perhaps is that wordsmith is not usually associated with speakers....If you are smithing your words, you ain't churning them out. It's laborious work to be a wordsmith.

Comment: What a fast talker [colloquial].

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***silver-tongued devil***

> *Silver tongue* is an expression used to describe a person who has a clever way with words.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Tongue)
>
> **silver-tongued**
>
> *adj.* Having or exhibiting the power of fluent and persuasive speech; eloquent.
>
> [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/silver-tongued)
>
> *Taylor got us out of trouble with the police. What a **silver-tongued devil**!*

Answer (score 0):

- Eloquent
- Persuasive
- Loquacious

I think any of those words would work. Not so much loquacious because it describes someone who talks a lot in general.